# Dynamically change the increase and decrease height and position of the uiview with animation while scrolling the uicollection view

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

when i scroll up the collection view, **3rd view** has to decrease the height and move behind the **2nd view** with animation, and the **2nd view** has to decrease the height and move behind the **1st view** with animation. and vice versa has to happen when we scroll down the collection view. for more details look on to the comment section. i have attach the example link.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOyc5.png)

Comment: https://github.com/telly/TLYShyNavBar/blob/master/resources/battle-tested-demo.gif

Comment: Please answer my question friends